# Can't view adcampaigns, even with ads_management permission enabled

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads

I am working with the Facebook Graph API using an account that manages a few other accounts. I can perform most operation just fine, such as adgroups, stats, etc. However, when I try to call adcampaigns or adcreatives I get the error message:

> (#294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management, and a participating API key

This also happens in the graph explorer. I generate a token and I check the ads_management permission and run the same operations, but I get the same problem. I can call adgroups, adaccounts, stats, etc., but I cannot call adcampaigns or adcreatives. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273679/offline-access-and-api-key-confusion

Comment: I'm also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jorge this just means that you need to apply to have your Facebook app given the capability to call into the Facebook Ads API.  Once your app is approved, you'll be able to call into the Ads API.  You can start the process here:

https://developers.facebook.com/marketingapis/