# Offline_access and Api-Key confusion

Tags: offline, api-key, facebook-ads-api

I've tried do develop automatic code that would fetch data from ads campaigns under account. My plan is to have server that would query every day to get data from impressions/clicks/costs of ads and save it for later use.

I use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to get access_token for getting data (insights) from those campaign pages but when I log out to try offline_access it tells access_token is old, cause of password change or access_token getting outdated.

Isn't the whole point of offline_access to grant acccess when user is not logged in?

And besides that.. what's with most of my calls ending having reply as follows:
"(#294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management, and a participating API key"

I've given access_token that has ads_management, but I have no idea what this Participating Api key even means. Do I need to add this to url call or something? Where do I get this Api Key?

Edit: I want to be able to get data from add campaign pages, so I'm not talking about Apps in page

Answer (score 4):

You will want to read up on the deprecation of the offline_access here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

But most importantly follow the guide here on how to handle invalid access tokens:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/

You app is to monitor the error messages coming back from the API and handle it gracefully.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're trying to call Ads API methods - which is where the 294 error is coming from - that's a whitelisted program you need to apply to join

Comment: Ok, I've Applied for the Ads Api, and hope I'll get access for functions in that side.

I still don't understand this App_id/App_secret thing with generating access_tokens. What App_id/App_secret do I need to give when I need to gain access for all ads under account?

Comment: You will find out when they accept you to using the Ads API I would presume.  I don't have access to it, so I cannot really comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I found [this bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261586667241634?browse=search_4f106e42d66dd8403576950) can be reason of our problem. It's already accepted and assigned, but still not solved. I hope it's really bug and not a secure hole, that was closed :)